# How to edit text in picture after using the snipping tool?

Tags: ms-word

[a sample snipped picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rg1qV.png)

As you can see in the picture, lets say i want to give different names to the equation rather than 46.17 to lets say 1. Then how can I edit that by making sure the format and other texts are not affected.

Comment: You cannot _edit_ text in raster graphics. It is not text anymore

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. For how-to help, please visit http://answers.microsoft.con and post your query there.